# Is $f(x)=0$ a polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Is $f(x)=0$ a polynomial function?

we know that constant functions are polynomials of degree zero

But, does $f(x)=0$ follow this definition?

Comment: The zero function is a polynomial function of degree $-\infty$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$f(x)=0$ is a polynomial function, with degree $-\infty$ (by convention).

In this way, $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ and $\deg(f+g) \leq \max(\deg (f), \deg (g))$ are true for any polynomials $f$ and $g$.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to explain the convetion,

Comment: I've added a possible explanation.

Comment: But true also for $\,+\infty.\,$ It can be motivated by relating the degree (of a rational function) to the order of its (Laurent) power series at $\infty$, i.e its pole multiplicity, e.g. see the Wikipedia article on [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_%28algebra%29).

Comment: @BillDubuque: defining it as $-\infty$ (and not $+\infty$), also $\deg(f+g)\leq \max(\deg f, \deg g)$ stays true. I also added this to my answer.

Comment: Right, that's was what I was nudging at above (thankfully not too subtly).